# Is it possible to create fillable PDF from excel?

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

Currently, I have an excel file that upon launch it shows a userform where users can fill out a few text boxes/comboboxes and press create. Upon pressing create, it gathers stored data and creates a PDF that we send to vendors. It's essentially an invoice. The vendors that receive this PDF have to fill out a couple of lines and return it to us. Right now if they have no acrobat/reader experience, they're printing the PDF and then scanning and returning to us.

I want the vendors to be able to type in a few areas on the PDF and return it to us. My question is, can I create a fillable PDF from excel? Does anyone know how to do this using excel features or with VBA? Or any other method?

Thanks!
Brandon

Comment: There is a [question on Adobe forums](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1281654) which involves this, it's not the most easy VBA.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I was worried it would be a coord answer, but that makes sense. I'll start tinkering

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: Absolutely.
First you will start with a fillable pdf form. (you can create one using Adobe Acrobat or the older Adobe Designer)
It is my understanding, from your question that you would like to take some information, fill out a PDF, then send this to your client, to complete this. 
Using VBA you can do all of this in one single button.
I created a step-by-step video on how to use the SendKeys method to achieve this.
Please see the detailed instructional YouTube video here: [How to AUTOMATICALLY fill PDF forms using Microsoft Excel in 1 CLICK](https://youtu.be/uU55FCbPHCI)